# Voting system adds and subtracts 1-5 each time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I implemented a voting system 
http://ad1987.blogspot.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html

on my website.  It works perfectly, except for the fact that each time you vote up or vote down it can add anywhere from 1-5 or so votes.  The source code is pretty much the same to that on that website, so if you'd like to see it, please check it out there. For a live example:

http://www.campusbasement.com/cornell/entertainment/articles/927/electro-is-taking-over-the-world

Thanks

votes.php: http://pastie.org/1369778

Comment: Do you mean that a user can vote multiple times and you want to prohibit that?

Comment: No, sorry I didn't clarify. If you go to the second link I posted, and attempt to vote up on a comment, you'll notice that it might go from +5 votes, to +9 votes.

Comment: show us your code the original one obviously works as expected...

you can paste it here at http://pastie.org/ and link us the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar problem. Chrome for some still unknown reason downloaded each page twice, so the views counter was getting +2 each time.

I suppose you have a user table with user_id, and an article table with article_id.
So you can implement the check connecting this two tables with many-to-many relation. You should create an intermediate table with fields **post_id** - the post being voted for, **user_id** and optionally a **value** field (if the user decides to change his vote).
The first two fields might be a composite primary key.

So when user votes, you search for the row with the same post and user ids. If there are non - you add it.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm pretty new to PHP and MySQL but that makes sense.  Do you have a link to a tutorial that may be able to walk me through something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is **no check** wether someone has already voted. So you need to either set a cookie (which can fail quite often) or check IP and browser for example... The best thing would be to check the User ID (if it is only possible to vote when logged in).

// EDIT:
I just read in the comments of your first post that the problem is the vote count when voting just once...

Comment: I actually have it set to only be able to vote when the user is logged in.  What would be the best method to check if the userId has voted.  I'd rather avoid cookies if I can.

Comment: Honestly, it's not a huge deal if a user can refresh and vote again, but at some point in the future, I'd like to implement a check, so I might as well do it now, I guess.